# Thue equations solving with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, diophantine-equations

Could somebody tell me whether Reduce assumes (or not) the GRH when solving Thue equations?
Given its performances (related to timing) compared to PARI/GP when the "GRH assumed" flag is set to FALSE I suspect Reduce does not assume the GRH as well, but a precise answer would help, along with some hints about the "bad" performances of Reduce compared to thueinit/thue from PARI/GP.
NOTE: I'm using MATHEMATICA v11.1 (and PARI/GP) running under Windows 10, 64 bits pro with a 4 cores/8 threads Intel CPU.

Comment: For the GRH question, have you asked WRI? Someone from Wolfram, or someone who has asked Wolfram, might answer here. Asking the source seems a good thing to try. For the bad performances, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your feedback! My apologies for asking, but what WRI stands for? Otherwise, e. g. the equation 169x^4+390x^2y^2-75y^4=4 is instantaneously solved by PARI/GP (no solution) while Reduce drags during about 9 hours before I aborted the search. Note that the same equation with "=1" instead of "=4" is instantaneously solved by both Reduce and PARI/GP (no solution as well).

Comment: WRI = Wolfram Research Inc. If you have Premier Service (through your institutional site license, for instance), they're usually fairly responsive. I doubt very many people know the answer to the GRH question outside of the company.

Comment: The Thue solver is ``Reduce`ThueReduce[{f[x, y], m, degree}, {x, y}, True, 0]``, where you have to fill the first list. Your "=1" example would be ``Reduce`ThueReduce[{169 x^4 + 390 x^2 y^2 - 75 y^4, 1, 4}, {x, 
  y}, True, 0]``, which takes too long.  `Reduce` uses a different method on the "=1" problem but calls the Thue solver on the "=4" problem.  You can inspect the code with ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@Reduce`ThueReduce``. But it's probably easier to ask WRI than to hack around yourself.

Comment: ``System`ThueDump`Y3Bound[f[x, y], m]`` seems to compute the y bound (maybe?), and it takes forever for your "=4" problem.

Comment: Thanks again Michael for the interesting tips. I have not (yet) subscribed the Premier Service, but I'll ask the WRI, as you suggest; indeed I do not intend to attempt to hack the MATHEMATICA code :-)